# How to merge and interlace columns of NumPy object arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a NumPy object array that looks like this:

[image]

How can I merge the two columns and interlace them at each row? For instance, row 0 should be

```
[0.   79.682   131.428   172.698   ...]
```

Comment: Without further knowledge of the data structure, you can ‘interlace’ two arrays (or other iterable) into a single array as: `np.array(list(zip(a,b))).reshape(-1)`; where `a` and `b` are numpy arrays, in this case.

Comment: @S3DEV Thanks for the suggestion. That interlaced it row by row, so that the cells in column 0 became the even numbered rows, and the cells in column 1 became the odd number rows. But I need the numbers in each column to merge at the level of each row, and interlace. So [A B C] and [1 2 3] in the first row should become [A 1 B 2 C 3].

Comment: If you implement this *logic* (not exact code) it’ll get you there. Please update the question to enable us to replicate a sample of your data structure.

Comment: ... and a bit less verbose: `np.column_stack((a,b)).ravel()`